# is it possible for Wget to flatten the result directories?

Tags: bash, wget

Is there any way to make wget output everything in a single flat folder? right now i'm

`wget --quiet -E -H -k -K -p -e robots=off #{url}`

but i'm getting everything in the same nested way as it is on the site, is there any option to flatten the resulting folder structure? (and also the sources links on the index.html file)

Answer (score 0):

After reading on the documentation and some examples i found that i was missing the `-nd` flag, that would make wget just get the files and not the directories

correct call `wget --quiet -E -H -k -nd -K -p -e robots=off #{url}`